# ExtAudioFileGetProperty returns AudioStreamDescription with zero frame size

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio

I want to read the `AudioStreamBasicDescription` from an audio file as follows

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription asdb;
UInt32 propSize = sizeof(asdb);

OSStat stat = ExtAudioFileGetProperty(_audioFile,
                                      kExtAudioFileProperty_FileDataFormat,
                                      &propSize,
                                      &asdb);
```

That works fine, except that all fields but `mBytesPerFrame`, `mBitsPerChannel` and `mBytesPerPacket` are set correctly.

Why would these fields not be set?

That's what the `AudioStreamBasicDescription`'s fields look like

```
TotalFrames: 2628360
BitsPerChannel: 0
BytesPerFrame: 0
BytesPerPacket: 0
ChannelsPerFrame: 2
FormatFlags: 0
FormatID: aac 
FramesPerPacket: 1024
SampleRate: 44100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the comment above AudioStreamBasicDescription in CoreAudioTypes.h. It explains how depending on the format, some fields may not be filled in. Since AAC is a compressed format, not all of the fields can be calculated, and are therefore returned as 0.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I guessed it's because of AAC. I thought `ExtAudioFileRead` would decode to PCM on the fly.

Comment: It will decode on the fly but it needs to be in that process (of decoding) to be able to grab the next samples, etc. Sitting on disk, without parsing the file to a greater degree, that information isn't available. Hope this helps.

Comment: Switched to reading `CMSampleBufferRef`s from an `AVAssetReaderTrackOutput`. Works fine.